# Memory-efficient way of representing non-uniform datasets in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

I want to store my data in a nice way, so that I can later efficiently analyse/plot it using standard packages such as seaborn. Pandas seems to be the go to library for storing structured data. However, I cannot find a satisfactory way of using it to store non-uniform data.

Let's say I have 3 arrays, representing length of 100 rats, 1000 cats and 200 dogs.

```
ratLength = np.random.uniform(1, 2, 100)
catLength = np.random.uniform(2, 3, 1000)
dogLength = np.random.uniform(3, 4, 200)
```

To the best of my understanding, I have 2 options of storing such data in a Pandas dataframe

1. One row per animal. The first column would be animal kind (rat/cat/dog), the second the length.
2. One row per triplet of rat-cat-dog. In that case, I would have to pad the shorter arrays with `np.nan` so that they are all the same length

In both cases the storage structure forces me to significantly increase the memory footprint of my dataset. I presume one can construct even more pathological examples with more complicated datasets.

**Question**: Can you recommend a framework for python to handle non-uniform datasets in an efficient way. It can be a smarter way of using Pandas, or it can be  a different data storage library, I'm ok with both.

Comment: With option 1 you doesn't increase the memory footprint in any significant way.

Comment: @Stef I used to store 1300 floats and 3 strings. Now I store 1300 floats and 1300 strings, right?

Comment: why strings? see further down (was too long to put it in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment (too long to write as comment):

```
s = pd.Series()
rat = np.random.uniform(1, 2, 100)
cat = np.random.uniform(2, 3, 1000)
dog = np.random.uniform(3, 4, 200)
s['rat'] = rat
s['cat'] = cat
s['dog'] = dog
s.memory_usage(deep=True)
#10892
s.memory_usage(deep=True, index=False)
#10712
sum(map(sys.getsizeof, (cat,rat,dog)))
#10688
```

So the additional memory requirement is 180 B for the index and 24 B for the series overhead.

---

You can also store your data in long form (I think this is what you meant in your comment). In this case you should use a categorical index to store just 3 instead of 1300 strings:

```
s1 = pd.Series()
s1 = s1.append(pd.Series(rat, index=['rat']*len(rat)))
s1 = s1.append(pd.Series(cat, index=['cat']*len(cat)))
s1 = s1.append(pd.Series(dog, index=['dog']*len(dog)))
s1.memory_usage(deep=True)
#88400 --> 1300 strings! BAD
s1.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(s1.index)
s1.memory_usage(deep=True)
#11960 --> 3 categories
```

Comment: Thanks. Categorical Indices are very nice